# Custom WordPress function is not working inside Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, function, metadata

I'm developing this website: baikumotor.com

And I inserted the following custom-made function inside the `functions.php`:

```
function colorStock(){
    function display_color($color)
    {
        echo "<div class=\"colorStockItem\" style=\"background: ". $color .";\"></div>";
    }   

    $postID = get_the_ID();
    $colorStock = get_post_meta($postID, 'colorStock', true); //Get Colours available

    if ($colorStock != ""){
        $myArray = explode(', ', $colorStock);
            //print_r($myArray); 
            //echo $myArray;

        foreach ($myArray as $item){ 

            $css_colors = array('naranja' => '#f58e08', 
                                    'rojo' => '#d40000',
                                    'azul' => '#3086d6',
                                    'blanco' => '#ffffff',
                                    'negro' => '#000000',
                                    'plata' => '#d0d0d0');

            foreach ( $css_colors as $colorname => $value) {
                if ($colorname == $item) {
                    display_color($value);
                } 
            }
        } 
    }


}
```

It's supposed to show the colours available for each bike. By taking the names of the colour (if available) from a custom meta_field on each post.

The thing is that whenever I place the `colorStock();` function inside the products loop, it will load fine in the latest bike, but as soon as it gets to the point where it should load the colors from the next product, it will stop loading the content (the HTML) and leave the page incomplete.

I would like to know why is it breaking the page loading and how to fix this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would organize everything differently. Try rewriting your function like this:

```
function colorStock($colors)
{
    $css_colors = array('naranja' => '#f58e08', 
                        'rojo' => '#d40000',
                        'azul' => '#3086d6',
                        'blanco' => '#ffffff',
                        'negro' => '#000000',
                        'plata' => '#d0d0d0');

    $colors = str_replace(' ', '', $colors); //Strip out the spaces first
    $myArray = explode(',', $colors);
    $output = '';

    foreach($css_colors as $colorname => $value){
        if(in_array($colorname, $myArray)
            $output .= '<div class="colorStockItem" style="background: '.$value.';"></div>';
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Then call in your loop like so:

```
<?php
$postID = get_the_ID();
$colorstock = get_post_meta($postID, 'colorStock', true);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<!-- YOUR LOOP CONTENTS -->
<?php
//YOUR COLORS
echo $colorstock ? colorStock($colorstock) : 'No colors found';

endwhile;endif;
?>
```

**ADDITIONAL SUGGESTION:** To keep things even more organized, you can probably do away with checking a color array entirely, and stick to class names in your stylesheet to define your background colors:

```
function colorStock($colors)
{
    $colors = str_replace(' ', '', $colors); //Strip out the spaces first
    $myArray = explode(',', $colors);
    $output = '';

    foreach($myArray as $class)
        $output .= '<div class="'.$class.' colorStockItem"></div>';

    return $output;
}
```

Call like so:

```
<?php
$postID = get_the_ID();
$colorstock = get_post_meta($postID, 'colorStock', true);
if(have_posts()) : while(have_posts()) : the_post();
?>
<!-- YOUR LOOP CONTENTS -->
<?php
//YOUR COLORS
echo $colorstock ? colorStock($colorstock) : 'No colors found';

endwhile;endif;
?>
```

And then in your stylesheet:

```
<style type="text/css">
.colorStockItem{background: #000;} /*DEFAULT*/
.naranja{background: #f58e08;}
.rojo{background: #d40000;}
.azul{background: #3086d6;}
.blanco{background: #FFF;}
.negro{background: #000;}
.plata{background: #d0d0d0;}
</style>
```

But you might have your reasons for splitting it up, so just do what you feel is best.